# Custom menu creation

Tags: menus

So I wrote my first custom menu with a walker.

In the admin panel I see the locations, so they are registered. 
The problem is that the very first menu I created gets added to all the locations. I can create a second menu but when I try to add it to a location, after I hit save nothing happens. Page reloads, and the first menu remains added to all locations.

Anybody can help me?

Comment: Does this happen on a vanilla WordPress install?  With no plugins and a default theme (2012, 2013, 2014) activated?

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: @Andrew Bartel thanks, I actually managed to solve it based on your response. Problem was I have not used menu location names as indexes of the associative array when registering menus, but they were the actual elements. Fixed this and problem was solved.